# Sql query distinct + other columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct

For example, I have such sql table of messages:

```
Id   from_user_id   to_user_id    message
1    1              2             Hello
2    1              2             How are you?
3    1              3             Where are you?
```

And query SELECT DISTINCT to_user_id FROM messages; it returns

```
to_user_id
2
3
```

But, that is not enough. I need to show all last messages of from_user_id(id=1) to others users, and avoid N+1 queries problem. The result must be like this

```
Id   from_user_id   to_user_id    message
2    1              2             How are you?
3    1              3             Where are you?
```

Comment: is there a column for `timestamp` of the last message?

Comment: yes, it is, but it's not important, i can sort by id or other columns. More important to get only one row for each user with one query, order is not important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to do a self join:

```
SELECT    m.*
FROM      messages m
LEFT JOIN messages _m ON m.to_user_id = _m.to_user_id
AND       _m.id > m.id
WHERE     _m.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Cool, can you say, how can I do it in ActiveRecord? I am using Ruby on Rails

Comment: Unfortunately I am unfamiliar with Ruby on Rails

Comment: If someone interested, on ruby on rails, it's similar: @messages = Message.joins('LEFT JOIN messages _m ON messages.to_user_id = _m.to_user_id AND _m.id > messages.id').where("_m.id IS NULL")

Answer (score 2):

Postgres offers `distinct on`, which is generally the best way to approach this type of problem:

```
select distinct on (to_user_id) m.*
from messages m
where m.from_user_id = 1
order by to_user_id, id desc;
```

Comment: Wow. that's really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the analytic function rank, and order it within a group...

```
select * from (
select id,
       from_user_id,
       to_user_id,
       message,
       rank () over (partition by from_user_id, to_user_id order by id desc) rnk
from   table_name
) t1 where rnk = 1
```

This is assuming that the id column is sequentially generated number, so message with id 3 was created after message with id 2. Usually, if you have a timestamp column, it would be more logical. In that case, you could use `order by timestamp desc`

Comment: I tried your version, but it returned: ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM (

Comment: Sorry I am used to the Oracle syntax... updated my query to include an alias for the inner query